# Catch-all route for Twig templates

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm creating a website which consits of several apps (I created a bundle for each of them) and a number of "*semi static*" pages.

This semistatic pages are Twig templates which don't need a controller because they just contain HTML code and in some cases an `{% extends %}` to use a certain template and `{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}` to show certain content only to admins.

I know about the `FrameworkBundle:Template:template` controller that Symfony 2.1 introduced, but I can't use this one because and I can't add a route for each "static" page that the designer creates.

Moreover, the URLs for these static pages may have one or more subdirectories (/one, /one/two, /one/two/three...) so I came up with this solution where, if the designer wants the URL to be mywebsite.com/part1/part2/part3 he will store the views in StaticBundle/Resources/views/part1/part2/part3.html.twig and the controller will generate the path NectStaticBundle:Default:part1/part2/part3.html.twig

```
/**
 * @Route("/{part1}")
 * @Route("/{part1}/{part2}")
 * @Route("/{part1}/{part2}/{part3}")
 * @Route("/{part1}/{part2}/{part3}/{part4}")
 * @Route("/{part1}/{part2}/{part3}/{part4}/{part5}")
 */
public function proxyAction($part1='', $part2='', $part3='', $part4='', $part5='') {
    $parameters = func_get_args();
    $parts = array_filter($parameters, 'trim');


    $templatePath = "NectStaticBundle:Default";
    for($i = 0; $i < count($parts) - 1; $i++) {
        if($dir = $parts[$i])
            $templatePath .= "/$dir";
    }
    $name = $parts[$i];
    $templatePath .= "/$name.html.twig";
    $templatePath = preg_replace("/\//", ':', $templatePath, 1);


    $response = $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse($templatePath);
    return $response;
}
```

I know this is a big ugly hack and it sucks, so I was wondering if someone knows of a better way to achieve this.

Comment: please review my answer and comment if something's missing / not working - otherwise accept please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * @Route("/{part1}/{part2}/{part3}/{part4}/{part5}")
 */
 public function proxyAction($part1=null, $part2=null, $part3=null, $part4=null, $part5=null)
 {
      $parts        = array_filter(array($part1, $part2, $part3, $part4, $part5), 'is_null');
      $template     = array_pop($parts);
      $templatePath = 'NectStaticBundle:Default/' .implode("/", $parts) . '/' . $template . '.html.twig'; 

      $response = $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse($templatePath);
return $response;
  }
```

Not tested but anyway .. you get the idea :)